# Notify slack user from Jenkins pipeline when build fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am sending slack notification to a channel from Jenkins pipeline, I have installed Jenkins slack plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack and configured Jenkins slack app to send notification to the channel whenever the build fails or succeeds. Instead of sending just a failure message to slack channel I want to notify the user saying that the build failed.
eg: `@user error in deploying following project`

I referred this steps from jenkins slack plugin

```
def userIds = slackUserIdsFromCommitters()
def userIdsString = userIds.collect { "<@$it>" }.join(' ')
post {
        // Send the build result to slack channel
        success {
          slackSend (color:'good', message: "<@$userIds>Successfully deployed")
        }
        failure {
            slackSend (color:'danger', message: "<@$userIds>Error in build ${env.JOB_NAME}")
        }
    }
```

I am getting null value for `$userIds` variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is only available for a bot user in slack, not for a Jenkins bot app.
The bot user which you create should have access to read and write message to the channel.

Answer (score 5):

If it is still relevant for someone, I did so:

```
........
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B ${GIT_COMMIT} | head -n1', returnStdout: true).stripIndent().trim()
                env.GIT_AUTHOR = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%ae ${GIT_COMMIT} | awk -F "@" \'{print $1}\' | grep -Po "[a-z]{1,}" | head -n1', returnStdout: true).trim()
                slackSend(
                    color: color_slack_msg(),
                    message: """
                        *${currentBuild.currentResult}:* Job `${env.JOB_NAME}` build `${env.BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}` by <@${env.GIT_AUTHOR}>
                        Build commit: ${GIT_COMMIT}
                        Last commit message: '${env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG}'
                        More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}
                        Time: ${currentBuild.durationString.minus(' and counting')}
                        """.stripIndent().trim(),
                    channel: 'slack-channel',
                    tokenCredentialId: 'SlackToken'
                )
            }
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}

def color_slack_msg() {
    switch(currentBuild.currentResult) {
    case "SUCCESS":
        return "good"
        break
    case "FAILURE":
    case "UNSTABLE":
        return "danger"
        break
    default:
        return "warning"
        break
    }
}
```

this will work if mail = login in slack